# How to add data to a Google Apps script in batches

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a gs script that connects to a MySQL Database and puts the results into a Google Sheet. The problem I am having is it is only inserting one row at a time on a loop and the total result set is far too large to do it that way.

```
function readData() {
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();
 var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, \':\', 2) as Hour, ticker, count(ticker) as count FROM wsb.data WHERE day =\'2021-01-29\' GROUP by SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, \':\', 2), ticker, day ORDER BY time desc ,count(ticker) desc');
 var metaData=results.getMetaData();
 var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 sheet.clearContents();
 var arr=[];

 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
   arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
 }

 sheet.appendRow(arr);

while (results.next()) {
 arr=[];
 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
   arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
 }
 sheet.appendRow(arr);
}




results.close();
stmt.close();
sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, numCols+1);
}
```

Is there a way to drop the entire result set from MySQL at once like I would copy/paste from MySQL results in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Check out the [`setValues()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function readData() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, \':\', 2) as Hour, ticker, count(ticker) as count FROM wsb.data WHERE day =\'2021-01-29\' GROUP by SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, \':\', 2), ticker, day ORDER BY time desc ,count(ticker) desc');
  var metaData = results.getMetaData();
  var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.clearContents();
  var vA = [];
  var arr = [];
  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
    arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
  }

  vA.push(arr);

  while (results.next()) {
    arr = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
    }
    vA.push(arr);
  }




  results.close();
  stmt.close();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, vA.length, vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```